# How to meet other inventors?

Tags: social-networking

I want to meet some inventors to see if the career if for me.
Where could I go to meet some of them?
I have tried Reddit, Discord, and Meetup.

Comment: Very, very few people make a living as independent inventors. Most obtain inventorship on patents as part of their work as an engineer or scientist.

Answer (score 0):

There are inventor clubs in many locations. In the US there are sites that collects information about local clubs https://inventleader.org/inventor-groups/ and https://uiausa.org/

Be careful out there, many people are out to scam inventors.